# remove rows that contains null using cross join

Tags: sql, cross-join

I have my code:

```
SELECT Y.shipdate[Sent date], 
Rate_ = 'price' + Z.Which, 
Bill_ = 'bill' + Z.Which,
               Rate = CASE Z.Which
                    WHEN '1' THEN price1
                    WHEN '2' THEN price2 
                    WHEN '3' THEN price3
                    WHEN '4' THEN price4
                    WHEN '5' THEN price5
                    WHEN '6' THEN price6 END,
                Bill = CASE Z.Which 
                    WHEN '1' THEN bill1
                    WHEN '2' THEN bill2
                    WHEN '3' THEN bill3
                    WHEN '4' THEN bill4
                    WHEN '5' THEN bill5
                    WHEN '6' THEN billr6 END,        
   Y.duedate[Due Date], Y.recvdate[Received] 
   FROM tra Y
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1'  union ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL  SELECT '3' UNION ALL  SELECT '4' UNION ALL  SELECT '5' UNION  ALL SELECT '6') Z (Which)  
   WHERE name = 'test'
```

with output:

```
Sent Date                   Rate_   Bill_   Rate    Bill    Due Date                  Received
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price1  bill1   0.55    300.00  2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price2  bill2   0.04    2.00    2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price3  bill3   0.07    43.00   2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price4  bill4   0.00    0.00    2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price5  bill5   0.00    0.00    2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2015-12-22 00:00:00.000     price6  bill6   0.00    0.00    2015-12-16 00:00:00.000   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

I want an output that will only display rows with value in price and bill. Based on my sample, there should only be 3 rows in the output. thanks.

Comment: post your expected output. also if possible provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
where name = 'test'
and CASE Z.Which
         WHEN '1' THEN price1
         WHEN '2' THEN price2 
         WHEN '3' THEN price3
         WHEN '4' THEN price4
         WHEN '5' THEN price5
         WHEN '6' THEN price6 
    END <> 0.00
```

Cross join produces the Cartesian product of two tables. Unlike other JOIN operators, it does not let you specify a join clause. but in you case you are using filters to eliminate rows. In such a case better use a `Natural Join`

Comment: another problem, do you have an idea on how to remove the rate_ and bill_ column? thanks.

Comment: just remove those columns from select it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved by other ways also, but this is the most generic and would work in most RDBMS system. Use your main query as subquery and give `where` condition

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Y.shipdate[Sent date], 
Rate_ = 'price' + Z.Which, 
Bill_ = 'bill' + Z.Which,
               Rate = CASE Z.Which
                    WHEN '1' THEN price1
                    WHEN '2' THEN price2 
                    WHEN '3' THEN price3
                    WHEN '4' THEN price4
                    WHEN '5' THEN price5
                    WHEN '6' THEN price6 END,
                Bill = CASE Z.Which 
                    WHEN '1' THEN bill1
                    WHEN '2' THEN bill2
                    WHEN '3' THEN bill3
                    WHEN '4' THEN bill4
                    WHEN '5' THEN bill5
                    WHEN '6' THEN bill6 END,        
   Y.duedate[Due Date], Y.recvdate[Received] 
   FROM tra Y
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT '1'  union ALL SELECT '2' UNION ALL  SELECT '3' UNION ALL  SELECT '4' UNION ALL  SELECT '5' UNION  ALL SELECT '6') Z (Which)  
   WHERE name = 'test' ) TMP_TAB
WHERE RATE <> 0 AND BILL <> 0
```